# Query on same document attributes where two conditions apply

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

my collection looks like this:

```
[
  {
    testx: [
      {
        "amount": 1,
        "id": "test"
      },
      {
        "amount": 1,
        "id": "test2"
      }
    ],
    testy: [
      {
        "amount": 2,
        "id": "test"
      },
      {
        "amount": 1,
        "id": "test2"
      }
    ]
  }, 
]
```

I want to find documents where the ID of two subdocuments in an array are equal ("testx.id === testy.id") AND the "amount" attribute of both subdocuments are not equal.

So far I tried:

```
find({
  $where: "this.testx.id === this.testy.id && this.testx.amount !== this.testy.amount", 
})
```

and

```
find({
        $and: [
            {
                $where: 'this.testx.id=== this.testy.id'
            },
            {
                $where: 'this.testx.amount !== this.testy.amount'
            },
        ]
    })
```

sadly, none of those returns the document. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Edit: I only want to receive the documents where the conditions apply. Expected result would be:

```
{
testx:  {
        "amount": 1,
        "id": "test"
      },
testy: {
        "amount": 2,
        "id": "test"
      },
}
```

Comment: Why testx and testy are arrays?

Comment: @matthPen good point, there are multiple documents in it, i want to recieve only the ones where the specific conditions applies, Added example documents to the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @matthPen 's comment I could solve it with $unwind

```
.aggregate({
  $unwind: "$testx"
},
{
  $unwind: "$testy"
},
{
  $project: {
    testx: 1,
    testy: 1,
  }
},
{
  $match: {
    $and: [
      {
        $expr: {
          $eq: [
            "$testx.id",
            "$testy.id"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        $expr: {
          $ne: [
            "$testx.amount",
            "$testy.amount"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) operator to achieve what you want, without any js code!

```
db.collection.find({
  $and: [
    {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          "$testx.id",
          "$testy.id"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      $expr: {
        $ne: [
          "$testx.amount",
          "$testy.amount"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

you can test it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WJ_CwufL6H-).

Comment: $expr looks really promising, the problem I have now is that all subdocuments of an array are returned even tho only one fits the condition. Check: https://mongoplayground.net/p/0-26z1VGSoR i only want to receive the ID from the documents ("test") where this applies.

Comment: Please, update your question : what you have (including multiple documents with different values in arrays), and what you need (array filtered, etc...). You will probably need aggreggation framework

Comment: Yes sorry, Updated the question, added a document to each array where the condition not fits. Added expected return from query.